# Is there a way to change the thickness of the lines from loop to loop in algorithm using algorithmic2e?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

Let say I have the following algorithm

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\include{pythonlisting}
\begin{document} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
 initialization\;
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions\;
  \eIf{condition}{
   instructions1\;
   instructions2\;
   }{
   instructions3\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to add thicker vertical line to while loop and thinner to if loop.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Obviously, it is a request to be made directly to Christophe Fiorio maintainer of this package read the readme file here https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e